# Regex Phone number with dashes

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get a regex that will validate the following formats:

```
234-567-8901
1-234-567-8901
```

I have tried various examples, but not sure how to get the one that will take into account the possible 1- at the begging and still inforce the 234-567-8901.

Rules are, any digit, 2 or 3 dashes, if 3 dashes then 11 numberes, if 2 dashes then 10 numbers.

```
^[0-9-]*$
^[\d-]+$
^[\d-]+$
```

Comment: which language? which framework? use ready-to-use parsers

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use:

```
^(1-)?\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(1-)?`: Match optional `1-` at the start
- `\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}`: Match phone no string of 10 digits with hyphens after 3rd and 6th digits
- `$`: End

Answer (score 0):

```
 telephone: function (val, field) {
    return /^(\d{3}[-]?){1,2}(\d{4})$/.test(val);
},
telephoneText: "Invalid phone number",
telephoneMask: /[\d-]/
```

Check out https://regex101.com/ to test your regex.

Comment: This sort of code only answer is not helpful. The language or system it is written for is not stated. There is no description of what it does or how it works or how it answers the question.